# Laravel Sanctum Vue SPA CORS issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-cli, laravel-sanctum

I've setup a VUE frontend which connects and authenticates perfectly well with a Laravel backend, using sanctum. I'm able to login and successfully retrieve the logged in user by visiting /api/user. I believe I've followed all the config steps stated in the documentation.
Here is sanctum.php config for stateful domains:

```
'stateful' => explode(
    ',',
    env(
        'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,localhost:8080,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8080,::1'
    )
), //this is what is in my env SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=app.foo-bar.test:8080
//my laravel backend is running on foo-bar.test
```

Here is my session.php config:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null), //in my .env I have: SESSION_DOMAIN=.foo-bar.test
```

I have the sanctum middleware setup in http/kernel.php, and I'm using auth:sanctum in my routes

Here is my cors.php config:

```
 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'logout'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

and in my vue frontend, I've configured axios to use the following

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://foo-bar.test';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

As I mentioned, I'm able to successfully login, and even visit /api/user. All works fine,
But when I make a post request to: api/users/multiple,
I get the CORS error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://foo-bar.test/api/users/multiple' from origin 'http://app.foo-bar.test:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm out of ideas, as it seems I've done all the necessary config. Perhaps I'm missing something ? Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Does adding the specific URL to your "paths" array, like ''api/*/*'' help?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat yes It tried that as well, same error

Comment: @MGS Do you already fixed this issue? I aslo faced this problem too on the production server.

Comment: @SokChanty make sure your front end is running on a subdomain of your backend.
e.g if your laravel app is running on foo-bar.test, then your vue app should be running on app.foo-bar.test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I came to realise was that this was not actually a CORS issue. If it was a CORS issue, I would not have been able to login, or visit the API that returns the currently logged in user.
What actually happens is that, chrome sometimes fails to report 500 errors on the API and rather returns CORS errors. When I tried making the API call on Firefox, I was able to actually see the 500 error.
Once I resolved the 500 error, the CORS error also stopped appearing in chrome.
What I've seen from this is that the network request error reporting on Firefox is more reliable than that on chrome

Answer (score 1):

Add a middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

In app/Http/kernel.php paste this in $middleware

```
protected $middleware = [  
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
     ....
];
```

In Middleware/Cors.php now add

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
 {
    return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, 
     OPTIONS')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- 
     Type, Accept, Authorization');
 }
```

Comment: Did not work, laravel 8 - 2022

Comment: Did not work , laravel 9 vue3

Comment: its not working with laravel 9 sanctum